# Upgrade issue for {{each}}

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading my application to ember 1.9.1 from 1.8.1. I got a deprecation notice for {{each}}

> DEPRECATION: Using the context switching form of {{each}} is deprecated. Please use the keyword form (`{{#each foo in bar}}`) instead. See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope for more details.

I have this each statement where bands is an array of objects

```
{{each bands itemView='matrix_band' itemController='matrix_band'}}
```

I have tried several options like

```
{{each band in bands itemView='matrix_band' itemController='matrix_band'}}
```

but the band object is not being passed to my controller correctly so I can not access any values off of the band object.

Comment: Can you duplicate your issue in jsbin?

Comment: I'll try but finding a generic example may take a little bit

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming from a route:

```
{{each band in model itemView='matrix_band' itemController='matrix_band'}}
```

Within a component:

```
{{each band in content itemView='matrix_band' itemController='matrix_band'}}
```

Comment: it is in a component and bands is passed in

Comment: Maybe, I wasn't 100% clear, i need to maintain bands. I did try {{each bands in content...}}